# Rspec is considering an attribute as a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to post an authenticate method:

```
post :authenticate, params: 
  { 'email' => @user.email, 'password' => @user.password }
```

This user is created on `before(:each)`

```
before(:each) do
    @user = User.create([
        { name: 'Robot', email: 'robot@email.com', password: '123456', age: 10 }
    ])
end
```

but Rspec is considering email and password as methods and I get this error

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `email' for #<Array:0x00559ddd541d18>
```

if I change `@user.email and` `@user.password` to string the test pass.

I would like to know if I can say to Rspec to consider `.email` and `.password` as attributes of user and not methods.

Comment: What's the value of `@user`?

Comment: @LucasAndrade , where and how are you defining the instance of user for Rspec?  Also are you using factory girl along side Rspec?  The error indicates that the query for the instance of a user is not giving you back a single instance(ie: find), rather it is giving you an array(ie: where).  Please show code when you get a chance. Please show code of how you are creating a user in the before block and also the whole test file if possible.

Comment: @kparekh01 I added my before each. I get it now, I am creating an array of users, so I need to use @user[0].email @user[0].password

Comment: Your way certainly works but there's no need to make an array, just apply the answer from below in to your before block and you're on your way.  Glad you figured it out though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing an array containing a hash to the create method. That's why Rails recognizes it as an array and not an User object.

Consider this example:

```
@user = User.create email: 'foo@bar.com'
@user.email # 'foo@bar.com'
@user.class # User(id: integer, ...)
```

And:

```
@user = User.create([{ email: 'foo@bar.com' }])
@user.email # NoMethodError: undefined method `title' for #<Array:0x007f8701b05b28>
@user.class # Array
```

In case you want to iterate over an array of hashes, to create certain users you'd need to iterate each of them and then create the user, like:

```
[
  { name: 'Robot', email: 'robot@email.com', password: '123456', age: 10 }
  { name: 'Other Robot', email: 'other@email.com', password: 'other password', ... },
].each { |user| User.create user }
```

But I think that's not the case now. You can just pass the user attributes separated by comma (a hash would be superfluous and an array would give you that result).

Try instead:

```
before(:each) do
  @user = User.create name: 'Robot', email: 'robot@email.com', password: '123456', age: 10
end
```

Note `before(:each)` can be shorten to `before do ... end`, and that instead using instance variables, you can use `let`:

```
let(:user) { User.create name: 'Robot', email: 'robot@email.com', password: '123456', age: 10 }
before { user } # before each test, creates a user named "Robot"
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. Since I am using only one User object, your solution in "Try instead:" works just fine. `before(:each) do
  @user = User.create name: 'Robot', email: 'robot@email.com', password: '123456', age: 10
end`

Comment: That's great. You could also take a look to FactoryGirl (known now as FactoryBot) for handling the fixtures creation when testing, it might be useful. Glad to help.